# Counting only specific element

Tags: xml, xslt

EDIT: Sorry the question was a bit unclear, I'm trying to return all the text in p nodes and their children while counting the individual p nodes. So <1> refers to the first p node, <2> to the second and so on.

I'm trying to count the occurrence of an individual element regardless of where it appears in the structure of the xml document. I've tried variations of position() and count() both with and without for-each loops and can't seem to find anything that will work. Anyone have an idea on how to do this?

An example document would be:

```
<text>
   <body>
     <div1>
       <p>abc</p>
         <div2>
           <p>def</p>
         </div2>
     </div1>
     <div1>
       <p>ghi</p>
         <div2>
           <p>jkl <name>adam</name></p>
           <div3>
              <p>mno</p>
           </div3>
         </div2>
     <p>qrs</p>
     </div1>
 </body>
</text>
```

with the return:

```
<1>abc
<2>def
<3>ghi
<4>jkl adam
<5>mno
<6>qrs
```

Comment: Question is unclear. What do the numbers in the desired output represent ? They clearly aren't position or count.

Comment: Why are you missing here "adam" -- the string value of `<name>`? Please, explain.

Comment: "adam" is present after <4>jkl. I'm trying to extract the text of p and all child nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xsl:number` is your friend here. Just use this to get the number

```
<xsl:number select="p" level="any" />
```

Note the use of `level` in this instance.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text" />

   <xsl:template match="p">
       <xsl:number select="p" level="any" />
       <xsl:value-of select="concat(') ', ., '&#10;')" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should output the following

```
1) abc
2) def
3) ghi
4) jkl adam
5) mno
6) qrs
```

Note the use of the template matching `text()` to stop text in elements other than `p` being output (should you have any).

Answer (score 0):

Before seeing Tim's answer I thought you may be interested in *any* text nodes *anywhere*.

I'm still not sure you mean just `p` nodes, so here's my solution that lists all text nodes that have no text ancestor, which produces the same result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="//*[text()][not(ancestor::text())]">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;', position(), '&gt; ', current(), '&#x0A;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<1> abc
<2> def
<3> ghi
<4> jkl adam
<5> adam
<6> mno
<7> qrs
```

Comment: Borodin, A text node cannot have a text node ancestor. Also, due to some reason your transformation doesn't show the white-space-only text nodes. One needs to explicitly eliminate these in the XSLT transformation and not to rely on the behavior and external settings of the XML parser that is used.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: What you say makes sense: logically, a text node can only ever be a member of the `child` or `descendant` axes. Originally I had `ancestor::*/text()`, and experimentation told me that `ancestor::text()` is equivalent using all the engines I had access to. Saxon, .NET, and MSXML all work identically. As for all-whitespace text nodes; why doesn't `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` deal with that?

Comment: This is close, but I'm trying to only count the p nodes. If "<5> adam" wasn't eliminated from the output (and followed by "<5> mno <6>qrs" that would have been what I was looking for.

Comment: @Borodin, `ancestor::text()` doesn't select anything -- a text node by definition doesn't have children. And I missed to see the `xsl:strip-space` directive -- probably I was looking at TimC's code.